# Closing popup form after 'Subscribe' button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, mailchimp, elementor

On my Wordpress website (built with Elementor), I show a popup email signup form for visitors.

After they click "**SUBSCRIBE**", I want the popup form to close, without redirecting them to any Mailchimp thank you page or my own page. Just close the popup and let them continue browsing from where they were originally at.

Below is my code (actual URLs replaced with fake ones) which was generated by Mailchimp Forms page:

```html
<!-- Begin Mailchimp Signup Form -->

<link href="//cdn-images.mailchimp.com/embedcode/horizontal-slim-10_7.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<style type="text/css">

#mc_embed_signup{background:#fff; clear:left; font:15px Montserrat,Arial,sans-serif; width:100%;}

</style>

<div id="mc_embed_signup">

<form action="https://justatestwebsite.com/subscribe/post…" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>

<div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">

<input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="email" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="email address" required

<div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true"><input type="text" name="b_6a7195cfk83j790ejfjas12vbbfab8d0_eb4f922797a" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>

<div class="clear"><input type="submit" value="SUBSCRIBE" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" ></div>

</div>

</form>

</div>

<!--End mc_embed_signup-->
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you submit form with Ajax ? Do you have any response from Mail service for next steps ? How you show popup ? with Div or opening new window ?

Comment: you can make changes in mailchimp plugin settings to submit form with ajax.

Comment: @Mohammad Not sure how to submit form by Ajax. Do I have to add some code to above code? The popup box is showed using Elementor (it has a feature that shows popup boxes, and I can just put whatever code I want in that box).

Comment: @ParthShah How? Which Mailchimp plugin?

Comment: @IlloYonexIllo How did you create email plugin ? do you using specific plugin to handle newsletter ?